# usar INNER JOIN EN UNION ALL

Tags: sql, subconsultas

tengo una consulta en SQL donde estoy usando UNION ALL para juntar dos select solo que en la primera consulta tiene un campo de codigo de moneda y en la segunda consulta no la tiene.

estoy revisando si se puyede hacer por medio de un INER JOINT juntandoo las dos tablas pero sigue apareciendo el error.

```html
SELECT 
cast(floor(cast(A.Invoice_Date as float)) as datetime) as 'Fecha',
@Diario AS 'TIPO',
A.Invoice_No,
A.Currency_Code,
A.Amount,
C.Account_No,
B.Supplier_Code
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Invoice A
INNER JOIN Common_v_Supplier B ON A.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
INNER JOIN Common_v_Supplier_Accounting B1 ON A.Supplier_No = B1.Supplier_No
INNER JOIN Accounting_v_Account C ON B1.AP_Credit_Account_Key  = C.Account_Key
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,A.Paid_Date) BETWEEN @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin AND C.Account_No LIKE @Account_No --AND A.Supplier_No = '191423' --

UNION ALL

SELECT 
cast(floor(cast(C.Check_Date as float)) as datetime) as 'Fecha',
 @Egresos AS 'TIPO',
C.Check_No,
CONCAT ('-','',C.Amount),
D.Currency_Code,
C1.Account_No,
B.Supplier_Code
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Check C
INNER JOIN Common_v_Supplier B ON C.Supplier_No = B.Supplier_No
LEFT JOIN Accounting_v_AP_Invoice D ON C.Check_No = D.Check_Nos
INNER JOIN Common_v_Supplier_Accounting B1 ON B.Supplier_No = B1.Supplier_No
INNER JOIN Accounting_v_Account C1 ON B1.AP_Credit_Account_Key  = C1.Account_Key
WHERE CONVERT(DATE,C.Check_Date) BETWEEN @Fecha_Inicio AND @Fecha_Fin AND C1.Account_No LIKE @Account_No --C.Supplier_No = '191423' AND
ORDER BY B.Supplier_Code
```

ERROR de consulta
***Error converting data type varchar to numeric.***

creo que el error viene de esta linea de codigo

```html
LEFT JOIN Accounting_v_AP_Invoice D ON C.Check_No = D.Check_Nos
```

ahora no se si sea correcto hacer un INNER con la misma tabla del primer select ***Accounting_v_AP_Invoice A***

Comment: Sigue apareciendo un error? Cuál? *Estoy revisando*-> Ajá? y cómo te ayudamos? *"Usar Inner joint en union all"* -  No entiendo cómo escribes mal `JOIN` si lo tienes escrito **ocho veces** en la consulta sql. Es `JOIN`, no 'joinT'. Una cosa más. Llevas un año en el sitio. Ya debes saber que los títulos de las preguntas deben reflejar el problema al que te enfrentas, para ayudar a otros usuarios que tengan el mismo problema a llegar hasta la solución fácilmente.

Comment: @Arriel una disculpa no preste atención al publicar que me faltaba información.

Comment: "creo que el error viene de esta linea de codigo" por? sabes algo que nosotros no? lo que no sabemos, es los tipos de datos de nada de eso, asi que puede estar en cualquier lado el problema...

Comment: A como está la descripción del problema, lamentablemete no tenemos datos suficientes para emitir un diagnóstico y/o solución. Por favor considera incluir un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) que podamos analizar. Puedes ayudarnos a ayudarte a través de un [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si la idea general es hacer la cuadratura entre facturas y pagos (suena natural porque una tiene invoices y la otra cheques) y limpiando el código irrelevante:

```
SELECT 
  @Diario AS 'TIPO',
  A.Invoice_No,
  A.Currency_Code,
  A.Amount,
  ... 
 FROM Accounting_v_AP_Invoice A

UNION ALL

SELECT 
 @Egresos AS 'TIPO',
 C.Check_No,
 CONCAT ('-','',C.Amount),
 D.Currency_Code,
 ...
FROM Accounting_v_AP_Check C
```

Yo diría que el error viene de tener las columnas con el orden cambiado. En la primera el currency code aparece antes de amount y en la segunda, después.

De paso, para cambiarle el signo a un campo numérico no se concatena con un guión:

```
 CONCAT ('-','',C.Amount),
```

Sino que se multiplica por -1

```
 -1* C.Amount as Amount,
```

Comment: muchas gracias @ffflabs, pequeño detalle